# What does the meaning of this line of codes ` skills: { ...this.state.skills, [name]: checked }`?

Tags: reactjs, object

```
   class App extends React.Component {
  
    state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    country: "",
    tel: "",
    dateOfBirth: "",
    favoriteColor: "",
    weight: "",
    gender: "",
    file: "",
    bio: "",
    skills: {
      html: false,
      css: false,
      javascript: false,
    },
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
     
    const { name, value, type, checked } = e.target;
    console.log(e)
   

    if (type === "checkbox") {
      
      this.setState({
        skills: { ...this.state.skills, [name]: checked },
      });
      
    } else if (type === "file") {
      console.log(type, "check here");
      this.setState({ [name]: e.target.files[0] });
    } else {
      this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }
    console.log(this.state.skills)
  };
```

what does this line do?

```
skills: { ...this.state.skills, [name]: checked }
```

The `...this.state.skills` may be using the spread operator to copy the object but I do not know the meaning of `[name]: checked`, the purpose of it is to change the value of key in the skills obj to `true` but I don know how it can be.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question, lots of stuff going on in the following line. So good catch to learn new stuff.

```
skills: { ...this.state.skills, [name]: checked }
```

##### named property

Normally we do `obj = { "abc": 3 }`, but what if the "abc" is stored in a variable `name`? That's why this `[name]` comes to play. Otherwise we have to do `obj[name] = 3` which takes additional effort. Also notice the difference between it with `obj["name"] = 3`. These two versions are very different.

##### spread operator

If we do `a = b` for an object, it doesn't make a new memory for `a`.

To create a new `a`, we do `a = { ...b }`. It takes out every first level property out of `b` and borrow them into a new memory space for `a`. Essentially a spread operator implies a new variable.

However only `a` is a new variable, none of the things you borrowed from `b` is re-created unless they are primitive variables. So we can not call a spread operator a deep copy. Maybe we call it a shallow copy, i don't know the right name ;)

Comment: thank you but what I've been confused is that how could the value of the key in the skill is assigned to `checked` but we got the final value is `true`

Comment: it's not dealing with `checked`, it's saying if you have a `<input name="abc" />`, it'll assign `obj.abc = true`